# Identify features of a person in text using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, text, nlp, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I want to be able to find all the features that refer to a specific person in text.

For example, if I had the string "John Smith is a Doctor and lives in Sydney, unlike his co-worker Jane who lives in Newcastle.", is there an NLP technique to extract only the information that relates to John? I.e. {John: Doctor, Sydney}.

Sub-question: is there a Python library that lets me do this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There is not a library that will just do this for you, but you can use dependency parse data you get from spaCy, for example. How you do it is out of scope for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Looks like I will have to make this independently - thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AMR (abstract meaning representation)
https://amr.isi.edu

It goes further than dependency parsing and will extract semantic relations.

[image: graph for John Smith is a doctor and lives in Sydney]

the graph shows that there is a doctor who is a person and their name is John smith and this same doctor is the agent of live and the location of living is a city called Sydney.

The accuracy for longer and more complex sentences might be low.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I will look in to it :)